# Notification of destruction of a child component to a parent component

Tags: angular

Is there a way that i can get to know if the child component was destroyed. I am aware of the ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook however my need is a little different.

I want the parent component to be informed if the child component was destroyed.

I already know that services can help or it can also be achieved via event emission. What i really want to know is that if there is a way which angular provides something like a flag that the component was destroyed or maybe a method that i could associate in order to extract this information.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you not emiting (using @ Output) in ngOnDestroy?

Answer (score 2):

As @Eliseo in the comments sections pointed out, you can make your parent component bind an event from your child component that, when the child component is being destroy, notify the parent component throw that event.

As you can check the following example, the child component provides an event called `beingDestroyed`.The parent component is binding a function called `childBeingDestroyed`to the event `beingDestroyed` <<`(beingDestroyed)=childBeingDestroyed()`>>.

Parent component:

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: ` <h1>I'm a parent<h1>
              <button type="button" (click)="show=false">Click Me And I will destroy the child component!</button>
              <child *ngIf="show"
                 (beingDestroyed)=childBeingDestroyed()
              >
              </child>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  show:boolean = true;

  childBeingDestroyed(): void{
    alert("Child Being Destroyed");
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: ` <br><br>I'm a child<br>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnDestroy  {
  @Output() beingDestroyed = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.beingDestroyed.emit();
  }
}
```

And in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uj4to?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.ts), you can find a full working example of this concept.

Comment: how can i achieve this knowing i have no capability to change the code of the child component? I'm trying to recieve an event when i destroy an element which was destroyed because an *ngIf statement, which i didn't have find a way to do that